# OpenCV issue: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' on a Mac

Tags: opencv, path, anaconda

I know I have OpenCV installed, the path is here: `cd /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2` The python interpreter allows me to run `import cv2` successfully with no error, yet when I run `import cv2` in Sublime text editor I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`

```
import cv2, sys, pytesseract
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3 in Sublime text editor searches in the default system locations when it tries to import Python modules, however you have installed OpenCV in a non-default location using Anaconda. Please append the path to cv2 to your system's path variable so that Sublime text editor can find it. To show the PATH in macOS type `echo $PATH` You haven't specified it in your question, but the path to `cv2` is something like `/home/autonocat/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/` Please check in Finder if this path is correct.

Alternatively install Spyder3 IDE in Anaconda and run the program from there. Spyder3 can do inline plotting.

[image]